# How to separate each array element with comma ( using replaceAll )?

Tags: java

I have an array with the name of coins and want to spare them with comma. In this class I want to print them with commas

```
class Coinscalculate {
    public void calc(double purchasePrice, double cash) {
        Coins obj = new Coins();

        int res = 0;


        if (purchasePrice == cash) {
            System.out.println(res);
        } else if (cash > purchasePrice) {
            cash -= purchasePrice;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.coins.length; i++) {
                if (cash > obj.coins[i]) {
                    cash -= obj.coins[i];
                    obj.coinsName.replaceAll("\\B", ","); // I tried to replace all but it didn't work
                    System.out.print(obj.coinsName[i]);
                    System.out.print(cash);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class contains my array.

```
class Coins {
    public double[] coins = {50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01};
    public String[] coinsName = {"Fifty Pounds", "Twenty Pounds", "Ten Pounds",
        "Five Pounds", "Two Pounds", "One Pound", "Fifty Pence",
        "Twenty Pence", "Ten Pence", "Five Pence", "Two Pence", "One Pence"};
}
```

Example of input : 11.25 20

Expected output : Five Pounds, Two Pounds, One Pound, Fifty Pence, Twenty Pence, Five Pence

Comment: give an exemple of the final array you want obtain

Comment: @kevinternet added

Comment: Don't give us exemple of your wrong output but the output you wish, so that we understand fonctional rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
class Coins {
    public double[] coins = { 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01 };
    public String[] coinsName = { "Fifty Pounds", "Twenty Pounds", "Ten Pounds", "Five Pounds", "Two Pounds",
            "One Pound", "Fifty Pence", "Twenty Pence", "Ten Pence", "Five Pence", "Two Pence", "One Pence" };
}

public class Coinscalculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calc(11.25, 20);
    }

    public static void calc(double purchasePrice, double cash) {
        Coins obj = new Coins();
        int res = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (purchasePrice == cash) {
            System.out.println(res);
        } else if (cash > purchasePrice) {
            cash -= purchasePrice;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.coins.length; i++) {
                if (cash >= obj.coins[i]) {
                    cash -= obj.coins[i];
                    cash = Math.round(cash * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    sb.append(obj.coinsName[i] + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
        String changeAmt = sb.toString();
        changeAmt = changeAmt.substring(0, changeAmt.lastIndexOf(",")); // Remove the last ','
        System.out.println(changeAmt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Five Pounds, Two Pounds, One Pound, Fifty Pence, Twenty Pence, Five Pence
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right:

```
System.out.print(obj.coinsName[i]+", "); //This adds commas
System.out.print(cash);
```

I  also don't understand what you mean by why is it
0.0499?
What should it be?

Comment: Actually my first  question is how to separate each index inside of array by comma